# How to get azure subscriptionid from subscription name using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to create a azure resource id in python script using information of provider and resourcegroup name. which will be used for rest api calls. But the problem is I have only name of subscription. How can I fetch subscriptionId in my prog?

Comment: You would need to get the list of all subscriptions and then find a matching subscription based on the subscription name.

Comment: To get the list of all subscriptions, you can use the SubscriptionClient in azure-mgmt-resource

Comment: +1 to Laurent, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.subscriptionclient?view=azure-python-preview for more detial

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by calling azcli in python to get the subscription details which follows

Here I am following [github code](https://github.com/msalvaris/amltoolz/blob/0bd79d55151688730bed224b76b360451b5712cd/amltoolz/subscription.py) to achieve your requirement

```py
def list_subscriptions():
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    subClient = get_client_from_cli_profile(SubscriptionClient)

except CLIError:
    log.info("Not logged in, running az login")

_run_az_cli_login()
    subClient = get_client_from_cli_profile(SubscriptionClient)
    return [["Subscription_name", "Subscription ID"]] + [[sub.display_name, sub.subscription_id]
        for sub in sub_client.subscriptions.list()
    ]
```

**Reference:**
[List subscriptions for a given Azure account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334789/list-subscriptions-for-a-given-azure-account)